# How to catch this error message in Python "is not recognized as an internal command"?

Tags: python, python-3.x, exception

I am using Python 3.7 with Windows 10 64 bits.
My python script needs to run some Windows program through the 'cmd'.
My python script previously installed these 'Windows program' and add their paths in the environment variable "Path".
But I still get this error message when the program is not recognized by Windows command:

```
'myWindowsprogram' is not recognized as an internal command
```

How can we catch this error message in Python in order to execute some other code and fix the issue with my code?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using

```
os.system
```

in that case, there may not be a way to capture the output.

From https://janakiev.com/blog/python-shell-commands/, try something like,

```
import subprocess
p = subprocess.Popen(['abc'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
```

that will give FileNotFoundError, so you can try to catch it like

```
try:
    p = subprocess.Popen(['abc'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
except FileNotFounError:
    # do something else
```